# Crear tabla temporal dinamica a partir del resultado de un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql, sql-server

Busco en MSSQL 2016 insertar el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado en una tabla temporal de manera similar a cuando se realiza el insert select desde una tabla, ya que el procedimiento arroja bastantes columnas como para declararlas en la tabla temporal desde el principio

```
-- codigo para crear una tabla dinamica temporal a partir de un select
SELECT * FROM table_test
INTO #tempData

-- lo que se busca realizar
EXEC 'procedimiento_almacenado'
INTO #tempData
```

cualquier tipo de ayuda es agradecida

Saludos

Comment: No se puede hacer lo que pides. Tienes que declarar la tabla desde antes.